# ImportError after upgrading python 2.7.3 to 2.7.6

Tags: python

I occurred into a question after installing python2.7.6.
   My system is Ubuntu12.10 with the python2.7.3 in path:`/usr/bin`. And I download the python2.7.6.tar then configure, make and make install to the path: `/usr/local/bin`. Then changed the `/usr/bin/python` linked to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.
   Then, when I trid to run the python file with the python2.7.6, got a ImportError like:
ImportError: No module named _ssl
ImportError: No module named zlib
...

But I can find ssl.py and zipfile.py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7. So How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the message about missing parts that shows up at the end of `make`, and follow the instructions to find what packages you need to install to successfully build the missing bits.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing compile-time dependencies for optional C extension packages.

Here is a list of packages I'd install if I were to compile Python on an Ubuntu machine:

```
build-essential
libncursesw5-dev
libreadline5-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libc6-dev
libsqlite3-dev
zlib1g-dev
tk-dev
```

The `libssl-dev` headers take care of the SSL module, `zlib1g-dev` for the `zlib` module.