# Problems installing module for python 3.5

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-3.5

Here is a possible duplicate of: [How to use pip with python3.5 after upgrade from 3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261468/how-to-use-pip-with-python3-5-after-upgrade-from-3-4)
I'm a newbie to the Python world. I was hoping someone might point me in the right direction.

**My current setup**

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 which already had python 2.7 and 3.4 installed.
I've downloaded Python 3.5.1 and executed `./Configure`, `make`, `make install` and installation seems fine.
I've also installed pip3 `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

**My problem**

pip3 installs my new libraries for Python 3.4, not Python 3.5.

**Looking at a solution**

As per the other post, I've executed the following:

`$ python3.4 -m pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
$ python3.5 -m pip --version
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip`

The other post also mentions that it could be a bug and that I could 'run pip through python' which I have no idea how to do.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` can only ever install `pip` into the system-provided Python version.

You'll need to get pip for Python 3.5. Python 3.5 comes with a module for this, called [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html):

```
sudo python3.5 -m ensurepip
```

This will locate and install pip for that specific Python installation.

Comment: Wow Thanks man. Getting another error with this:
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS.
Any thoughts?

Comment: @StevePaul: you installed Python without SSL support. Install the OpenSSL development headers and re-build (configure, make) and re-install Python.

Comment: @StevePaul: see [Recompiling python with SSL support on ubuntu](http://serverfault.com/q/353128) for example.

Comment: @StevePaul: you may be missing other features, see [ImportError after upgrading python 2.7.3 to 2.7.6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22934227) for a list of development packages I think is still up-to-date for Python 3.5 and Ubuntu.

Comment: This helped a great deal - thank you! Now I can execute pip3.5 commands. Awesome stuff.